# How to calculate confidence interval for intraclass correlation

Tags: independence, f-test, intraclass-correlation, dyadic-data

I am running an intraclass correlation to test for non-independence of the responses of individuals in dyads. I am running the intraclass correlation, as recommended by Kenny, Kashy, and Cook in *Dyadic Data Analysis* (2006), because my dyad-members are indistinguishable. I have calculated the intraclass correlation, and I now must calculate a 95% confidence interval to see if the confidence interval captures 0. (If it does, then the dyad-members' data points are independent.) Unfortunately, the book does not go as in-depth as I need to understand how to perform the 95% confidence interval, with my limited knowledge of statistics.

How do I perform a two-tailed F-test on my intraclass correlation, and how do I determine the upper and lower critical values for the F-test? I have very limited knowledge in statistics and I worry this is all way over my head.

After I determine the upper and lower critical values, the formula is:

[image: formula]

where FU is upper critical value and FL is lower critical value.

If it helps,

> Degrees of Freedom Numerator: 83
>
> Degrees of Freedom Denominator: 84.
>
> F = 1.3415

I really want to understand how to run this statistical procedure. Thank you so much in advance.